# Trying to make UiButton change a var in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am making an app in Swift and I want to make a button change a var. I have a button in each corner and name it them side it is on  and i want it  to change the number of swipedirection. When i try it never changes it

```
 @IBAction func right(_ sender: UIButton) {
    swipedirection = 1
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the value hasn't changed?

Comment: i have  swipedirection connected to text so when swipedirection = 1 it displays a set text. i also have tested it with a test var and it worked so it has to be button

Comment: Are you sure that `right(:)` invokes when you press button? Also can you add little more detail where you use `swipedirection`?

Comment: ok here is a more general question how do you use a UIButton in general to   change a var.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the tag property of UIButton. Let's assume you set this property (in IB but you can also do it in code) to be 0 for left and 1 for right. All you need to do in code is this:

```
var swipeDirection:Int = -1 // set this way to declare that nothings has been tapped

@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {
    swipeDirection = sender.tag
}
```

Note that you set **both** buttons to this. The easiest way (if you use IB) is to code the IBAction **first**, then command-drag from code into IB next.